# Golang Encode/Decode base64 with json post doesn't work

Tags: json, encryption, go, base64, aes

I build a client and a server in golang both are using this functions to encrypt/decrypt

```
func encrypt(text []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    b := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(text)
    ciphertext := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize+len(b))
    iv := ciphertext[:aes.BlockSize]
    if _, err := io.ReadFull(rand.Reader, iv); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBEncrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(ciphertext[aes.BlockSize:], []byte(b))
    return ciphertext, nil
}

func decrypt(text []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(text) < aes.BlockSize {
        return nil, errors.New("ciphertext too short")
    }
    iv := text[:aes.BlockSize]
    text = text[aes.BlockSize:]
    cfb := cipher.NewCFBDecrypter(block, iv)
    cfb.XORKeyStream(text, text)
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(text))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, nil
}
```

so yeah I make a normal post request

```
url := "https://"+configuration.Server+configuration.Port+"/get"

// TODO maybe bugs rest here
ciphertext, err := encrypt([]byte(*getUrl))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: " + err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(string(ciphertext))

values := map[string]interface{}{"url": *getUrl, "urlCrypted": ciphertext}
jsonValue, _ := json.Marshal(values)
jsonStr := bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue)

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, jsonStr)
```

and the servercode is as following

```
requestContent := getRequestContentFromRequest(req)
url := requestContent["url"].(string)

undecryptedUrl := requestContent["urlCrypted"].(string)
decryptedurl, err := decrypt([]byte(undecryptedUrl))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error: " + err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(decryptedurl)
```

where getRequestContentFromRequest is as following

```
func getRequestContentFromRequest(req *http.Request)                 
    map[string]interface{} {
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(req.Body)
    data := buf.Bytes()
    var requestContent map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &requestContent)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return requestContent
}
```

Now to the problem.
If I encrypt my string in the client and decrypt it direct after that everything is fine.

But, when I send the encrypted string to the server and try to decrypt it with literrally the same function as in the client, the decrypt function throws an error.

```
Error: illegal base64 data at input byte 0
```

I think the Problem is the unmarshalling of the JSON.

Thanks for help.

P.S.

Repos are

github.com/BelphegorPrime/goSafeClient and github.com/BelphegorPrime/goSafe

UPDATE

Example JSON

```
{"url":"facebook2.com","urlCrypted":"/}\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdgP\ufffdN뼞\ufffd\u0016\ufffd)\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdy\u001c\u000f\ufffd\ufffd\ufffdep\ufffd\rY\ufffd\ufffd$\ufffd\ufffd"}
```

UPDATE2

I made a playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/AHo_KJ5SyF)

Comment: The error is in decoding the base64 data, what makes you say the problem is in unmarshalling the JSON?

Comment: because it works with the same decrypt function on the client side. Without any error.

and "unencryptedUrl" on the server looks the same as "string(ciphertext)" on the client.

So I think something went wrong on the way from the client to the server.

Comment: The variable names are super confusing - `unencryptedUrl` is the raw input before you call `decrypt` on it, so it's actually the encrypted value, right? And the value that comes back out of `decrypt` is called `encryptedUrl` but it's actually the unencrypted value, since it's the resul of `decrypt`?

Comment: yeah you are right. I changed that and hope it is less confusing now.

Comment: What does the JSON look like? Since `urlCrypted` goes in as a `[]byte`, I would think it would remain a byte array, which means when you pull the data out, you should just cast it to `[]byte` instead of casting to `string`, then casting the string to a `[]byte`. It's _possible_ that's related to the issue.

Comment: values := map[string]interface{}{"url": *getUrl, "urlCrypted": ciphertext}
jsonValue, _ := json.Marshal(values)
jsonStr := bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue)

Comment: I tried casting it to []byte, but go throws the error         

interface conversion: interface is string, not []uint8

Comment: That seems odd to me. Can you add a sample of the JSON to your question?

Comment: Not yet but tomorw will be possible. In the mean time you could fork the repo if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you encode in base64 twice. The first time in the `encrypt` function and the second time during the JSON marshalling. byte slices are automatically converted into base64 strings by the `encoding/json` marshaller.

The solution is to decode the base64 string before calling `decrypt`.

Example on [the Go PlayGround](https://play.golang.org/p/taf4_Iofzp)

**EDIT**

Working solution [here](https://play.golang.org/p/VYE1uFQ5-o)

Comment: As you may have seen, I'm doing exactly that in the "getRequestContentFromRequest" function.

Comment: No, you don't base64 decode in that function. You have to base64 decode `requestContent["urlCrypted"]` before calling `decrypt`

Comment: I found several issues in the encrypt/decryp funcs. You have to encode after you encrypt and decode before you decrypt. Otherwise the json marshaller will receive a json string with unprintable characters and will encode in base64 again. If it receives a base64 string, it will send it as is. Check here https://play.golang.org/p/VYE1uFQ5-o